# Cannot debug for C++ code in Android Studio : java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Tags: debugging, android-studio, android-ndk, lldb

I Cannot debug for C++ code:

```
Error running Android Hybrid Debugger (14757): Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8602): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"
```

**Studio Build:**
Android Studio 2.2.2

**JRE:** 1.8.0_76-release-b03 amd64

**JVM:** OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

**Version of Gradle:**
gradle-2.14.1

**Version of Java:**
1.8.0_76

**OS:**
Windows 7 Professional SP1

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Run my app with "shift + F10"
2. attaching debugger, choose Debugger as "Auto" (also I've tried 'hybrid' or 'native', neither can works well)
3. android studio is showing "starting LLDB server..", and then showing the below error in event log:

   14:22:24 LLDBDriverException: unknown error
   14:22:25 Error running Android Hybrid Debugger (14757): Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8602): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"

Images as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF6xv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UcQF.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823082/unable-to-attach-debugger-in-android-studio-localhost8600-java-net-connectexc